# I have a developer token and installed the googleads package. How do I start using the Google Ads API with Python?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I've been trying to use Python to connect to the Google Ads API. I got a developer token and installed the googleads package in Pycharm. How can i start using the API? Trying to use Google's tutorial has been fruitless in my efforts for the last month.

Comment: Unlucky guiding you step by step through using a Google API is not service we can offer on SO. Do you have any specific question?

Comment: Really feel like I just need to know the first step here

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to make several API calls using python so I hope this helps somebody.

This is the function I use to retrieve all campaigns under an account:
I use the AWQL version since it is easier to understand.

```
def getAllCampaigns(service):
"""
Retrieve all campaigns under a account.

No campaigns will be returned when this function is ran from
a MCC account (having a MCC ID in googleads.yaml).
"""
# Using AWQL to retrieve campaigns.
query = (adwords.ServiceQueryBuilder()
    .Select('Id', 'Name', 'Status', 'StartDate', 'EndDate',
        'BudgetId', 'BudgetStatus', 'BudgetName', 'Amount',
        'BudgetReferenceCount', 'IsBudgetExplicitlyShared')
    .Limit(0, pageSize)
    .Build())
campaigns = []
# print('start loop')
for page in query.Pager(service):
    # print(page['totalNumEntries'])
    if page['entries']:
        for campaign in page['entries']:
            campaigns.append(campaign)
    else:
        print('no campaigns were found')
# print('end loop')
# print(campaigns)
return campaigns
```

This function requires you to pass a 'service'. To create such a service you will need to retrieve the information from the googleads.yaml file using the LoadFromStorage method.

Use following line to create a client which retrieves the information from the googleads.yaml file, this file defaults to the home directory, so make sure its there for now.

```
client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()
```

Use the following line to create the service that can retrieve campaigns.

```
service = client.GetService('CampaignService', version='v201809')
```

This page of the [AdWords API documentation](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields) contains all the services that can be used. Might be helpfull.

Now you can call the function created above like this and it will print all campaigns under an account.

```
result = getAllCampaigns(service)
print(result)
```

Do make sure that your googleads.yaml file contains the ID of a (test) client account, and not a (test) MCC account, since it won't print any campaigns when it contains the ID of a (test) MCC account.

I hope this example helps you or anyone that might come here.

Comment: Very well written!

Answer (score 0):

In the same boat as you but managed to at least get a connection going (or at least I think I do)

This link did it for me:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call

In terms of the steps:

1. Request a developer token.
2. Create test accounts.
3. Get a client library.
4. Set up authentication via OAuth2.
5. Get an OAuth2 refresh token and configure your client.
6. Make your first API call.

It looks like you've done steps 1,(2) and 3, guess next step would be 4 and you would need to make sure you have the right permissions to create oauth2 credentials via the google api console, follow the steps outlined in the link and then you'll get a refresh token.

Not going to lie, I'm stuck on step 6 myself...

Comment: I was able to use the get_campaigns.py example file to get my campaigns after properly configuring my googleads.yaml file